# Save static version of a webpage to be available offline

Tags: html

Is there a way to save a webpage as static HTML, available for offline viewing, editing etc.?

I want to remove all JavaScript files. Leave only HTML, CSS and images.

For example, if this web page has a Facebook Like button, I want the image of the button to be part of the HTML as a regular image (and not be loaded as some JavaScript code runs after I load the page).

I'm trying to prepare a webpage for an offline demo. When I use the standard "save as HTML complete" like tools, all the JavaScript is saved as well, and when viewed offline, all the dynamic content is blanks.

Note- I don't expect the dynamic content to work, of course, with no JavaScript. I just want the web page to LOOK as though it was just loaded from the interwebs.

Answer (score 2):

(Answering my own question): I found a nice (if not perfect) solution: the Scrapbook browser Add-On. There is one for Firefox http://amb.vis.ne.jp/mozilla/scrapbook/  and one for Chrome. The one for Firefox looks more feature-complete.
I'm going to test it and see how it works.

Comment: Scrapbook was awesome!  Did a great job.  Here's a link to Mozilla's official Add-On page: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/

Answer (score 1):

I like [Remy Sharp's inliner tool](http://inliner.leftlogic.com/). What it does:

- Get a list of all the assets required to drive the page: CSS, JavaScript, images and images used in CSS
- Minify JavaScript (via uglify-js)
- Strips white from CSS
- Base64 encode images
- Puts everything back together as a single HTML file with a simplfied doctype

Answer (score 0):

i think you are in a dilemma. if you strip the javascript, sure the dynamic aeras will be blank, because the javascript would have filled them after the page loaded. you could try with different browsers, but i think you just can't have the cake and eat the cake.

as a workarounds i suggest:

make screenshots of the website and put them into a pdf, or view them with an imageviewer.

or get an internetconnection for the demo.

or have the whole website on a local webserver on your demo-hw.

Comment: I have no problem with hosting the entire website on my PC (that's what I intend to do!). The problem is all the snippets of javascript code that load widgets, ads, share-buttons etc. They don't need to work, but I want the page to LOOK as though they were loaded. The page needs to retain the basic HTML functionality (a text box is still a text box).